# Sublime 3 Plugin Storing Quick Panel Return Val

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to write a simple plugin that generates a quick panel based on some list, waits for the user to select an item, and then performs an action based on the value the user selected. Basically, I'd like to do the following:

```
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        self._return_val = None
        self._list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    def callback(self, idx)
        self._return_val = self._list[idx]
    def run(self):
        sublime.active_window().show_quick_panel(
            options, self.callback)
        if self._return_val == 'a'
            // do something
```

However, show_quick_panel returns before anything is selected and therefore self._return_val won't be assigned to the index selected until after the if statement runs.

How can I solve this problem? With an event listener? I'm very new to Python and Sublime plugin development.

Answer (score 2):

The `show_quick_panel()` is asynchronous, so while it is executing the remainder of the `run()` method is finished executing. The action after selection should be done in the callback. The callback will only be called once the user has either selected an item from the quick panel, or dismisses it.

First, you are using a `TextCommand` so the signature for the `run()` method is `run(edit, <args>)`, it requires the `edit` argument.

Also note that the callback will receive an index of `-1` if the user doesn't select anything (dismisses the quick panel) e.g. if the user presses <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Here is the `show_quick_panel` API:

> **`show_quick_panel(items, on_done, <flags>, <selected_index>, <on_highlighted>)`**
>
> Shows a quick panel, to select an item in a list. `on_done` will be called once, with the index of the selected item. If the quick panel was cancelled, `on_done` will be called with an argument of `-1`.
>
> items may be a list of strings, or a list of string lists. In the latter case, each entry in the quick panel will show multiple rows.
>
> `flags` is a bitwise OR of `sublime.MONOSPACE_FONT` and `sublime.KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST`
>
> `on_highlighted`, if given, will be called every time the highlighted item in the quick panel is changed.
>
> — [Sublime Text API Reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)

Now, let's rework the example command.

```
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def on_done(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            # noop; nothing was selected 
            # e.g. the user pressed escape
            return 

        selected_value = self.items[index] 
        # do something with value

    def run(self, edit):
        self.items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        sublime.active_window().show_quick_panel(
            self.items, 
            self.on_done
        )
```

For some more examples on the usage of `show_quick_panel()` see my [polyfill](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-polyfill/blob/810b3baa3bf31303aeebe43aa4e829b74acd17ba/preferences.py) package.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the quickpanel obviously does not block the program execution. I recommend to create and pass a continuation:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExampleQuickpanelCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        # create your items
        items = ["a", "b", "c"]

        def on_select(index):
            if index == -1:  # canceled
                return
            item = items[index]
            # process the selected item...
            sublime.error_message("You selected '{0}'".format(item))

        self.window.show_quick_panel(items, on_select)
```

Comment: Inner functions (defing `on_select()` inside `run()`) are occasionally useful in Python but there is no reason to use one to define a callback in this case. [This page](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) explains extremely well when and why inner functions should be used. Gerard Roche's answer has a *textbook* example of how to use a basic `show_quick_panel()` and the `EnableColorSchemeCommand` class on the page he linked shows how to use it for everything other than adding `flags`.

Comment: @mattst Thanks for the feedback and the link. While I agree, that his answer is useful and correct, (I wouldn't have added my answer if his was already there.) I have to point out, that the way of passing the arguments can go wrong. If you use a `WindowCommand` or an `ApplicationCommand` *and* set the flag `sublime.KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST` you can open two quickpanels at the same time. Opening the second overwrites the items of the first one, if they are in the same window. This won't happen for TextCommand or inner functions/closures or w/o the flag.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem, [see the code](https://gist.github.com/mattst/1a7a194a76dd8e4f34b86cd3c3ff048c). I suppose that bug has been fixed; now if a quick panel has been created with `KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST` and you try to open another quick panel in the same view (or a different view in the same group) nothing happens except for a 'Quick panel unavailable' console message and the original quick panel continues to operate as it should. You can open additional quick panels in different groups in which case they are all visible and all operate correctly. Using: ST 3126

Comment: @mattst This is not a bug, but the expected and corrent behavior. I will post an example at the gist.

Comment: I see and you're right. But for that to occur you need the same plugin class to display different items in multiple quick panels called from different groups in the same window with `KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST` set and it doesn't happen if the class inherits `TextCommand` instead of `WindowCommand` or `ApplicationCommand`. Not circumstances that will occur all that frequently I'd say. Also I can't think of a reason why `KEEP_OPEN_ON_FOCUS_LOST` would actually be useful, after all the whole purpose of displaying a quick panel is to allow the user to select something.